# How to add multiple circles on Google map in vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vuetify.js

This is my code to load google map

```
<gmap-map
      :center="center"
      :zoom="8"
      style="width:100%;  height: 400px;"
    >
     
     
      <gmap-marker
      
      :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in myLatLng"
        :position="m.position"
       :icon="require('./../../../../assets/tower.png')"
      
      ></gmap-marker>
     
        <gmap-circle
        
          :key="index"
          v-for="(pin, index) in myLatLng"
          :center="myLatLng.position"
          :radius="3000"
          :visible="true"
          :options="{fillOpacity:0.5,strokeWeight: 0.5
}"
         
      
          
          >
        </gmap-circle>
    </gmap-map>
```

This is a 'myLatLng' object,

```
 myLatLng: [
      {position:  { lat:6.0535185, lng:80.2209773 }},
      {position: { lat:6.2036027, lng:80.4764655 }},
      {position:  { lat:6.296856600000001, lng:81.2357613}},
]
```

but I run the project these circles are not visible on the map. I want to display three circles use the 'myLating' position as a center point of the circle.  How I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to change from this:

```
    <gmap-circle
      :key="index"
      v-for="(pin, index) in myLatLng"
      :center="myLatLng.position"
      :radius="3000"
      :visible="true"
      :options="{fillOpacity:0.5,strokeWeight: 0.5">
    </gmap-circle>
```

to this:

```
    <gmap-circle
      v-for="(pin, index) in myLatLng"
      :key="index+'circle'"
      :center="pin.position"
      :radius="3000"
      :visible="true"
      :options="{fillOpacity:0.5,strokeWeight: 0.5}">
    </gmap-circle>
```

the problem is `:center="myLatLng.position"`

Comment: what are you meaning by using "index+'circle'" to key in gmap-circle?